# Running substring implementation written in python via matlab throws typeError

Tags: python, matlab, typeerror

I wanted to learn how to use python modules in matlab. Therefore I wrote a trivial implementation of substring:

```
def substring(string, end, start=0):
    if int(start) != 0:
        return string[int(start):int(end)]
    else:
        return string[:int(end)]
```

I put it into a file named substring.py which is saved in the matlab working directory.

I added matlab work folder to python search path (followed the instructions here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-defined-custom-module.html).

Then I tried to call my function in matlab:

```
x_label = py.substring.substring(fastaContent.id, int8(40));
```

I ran the matlab code and got this in console:

```
Error using substring (line 3)
Python Error: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

fastaContent.id is a valid string. I also wrapped 40 with `int8()` but it didn't help.

I would appreciate any help.

@Edit: I think it is worth mentioning that the function works fine called with python.

Comment: What version of MATLAB and what version of Python are you working with? I can run your function fine in R2018b and Python 3.6.1

Comment: Matlab R2018b and Python 3.6.0